# MSAL.js token is valid

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal

How check token is valid?

I run this and later I get token but I would like to check is valid

```
@action 
    signIn() {
          const loginRequest = {
            scopes: ["User.ReadWrite"]
        }

        this.userAgentApplication.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
        this._isLoggedIn = true;
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about id token or access token?

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity idToken from Azure

Comment: May I reason why would you want to check the token is valid or not? which is already authenticated and acquire from azure.

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity i send this token to API and from api I would like to check is valid token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app's registration screen, click on the API permissions blade in the left to open the page where we add access to the Apis that your application needs.

Click the Add a permission button and then,
        Ensure that the My APIs tab is selected.
        In the list of APIs, select the API TodoListService-ManualJwt.
        In the Delegated permissions section, select the Access 'TodoListService-ManualJwt' in the list. Use the search box if necessary.
        Click on the Add permissions button at the bottom.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                },
            });
    }
```

Please refer this document for [token validation with web api](https://github.com/Azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation)

Comment: thanks for help I accepted your answer and also I added point for your time

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript#sign-in-with-redirect 
you need to register a callback function in order to access/process the tokens.

> The redirect methods don't return a promise because of the move away
>   from the main app. To process and access the returned tokens, you need
>   to register success and error callbacks before you call the redirect
>   methods.

```
function authCallback(error, response) {
    //handle redirect response

}

myMsal.handleRedirectCallback(authCallback);
```

I think the token would likely be in the response somewhere.